# Issue with Zend Form hydrator Classmethod not binding properly to object entity

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-form2

I was trying to bind entity Contact with default values (using getters) to the form ContactForm using Classmethod() hydrator.

The problem is when I then call setData with a set of values, the Hydrator was not able to merge the default values and the set of values but instead it returned only the set of values. Kindly find below an excerpt of my codes.

```
<?php
// My contact form
namespace Application\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;

class Contact extends Form
{
    public function __construct($name = 'contact')
    {
        parent::__construct($name);

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Your name',
            ),
            'type'  => 'Text',
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'subject',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Subject',
            ),
            'type'  => 'Text',
        ));
        $this->add(new \Zend\Form\Element\Csrf('security'));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'send',
            'type'  => 'Submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => 'Submit',
            ),
        ));

        // We could also define the input filter here, or
        // lazy-create it in the getInputFilter() method.
    }


    public function getInputFilter()
    {
        if (!$this->filter) {
            $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
            $inputFilter->add(array('name' => 'name', 'required' => false));
            $inputFilter->add(array('name' => 'subject', 'required' => false));
            $this->filter = $inputFilter;
        }
        return $this->filter;
    }
}
```

Here's my entity

```
class Contact
{

    protected $name;
    protected $subject;

    /**
     * @param mixed $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $subject
     */
    public function setSubject($subject)
    {
        $this->subject = $subject;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getSubject()
    {
        // Trying to set a default value
        if (null == $this->subject) {
            return 'default subject';
        }
        return $this->subject;
    }

}
```

Here I test it in a controller action

```
class TestController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $data = array(
            'name' => 'myName'
        );

        $class = '\Application\Entity\Contact';
        $contact = new $class;

        $form = new \Application\Form\Contact();
        $form->setHydrator(new ClassMethods(false));
        $form->bind($contact);
        $form->setData($data);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            var_dump($form->getData());
        }
        die("end");
    }
}
```

I wanted to get

```
object(Application\Entity\Contact)[---]
    protected 'name' => string 'myName' (length=6)
protected 'subject' => string 'default subject' ...
```

But instead I got this result

```
object(Application\Entity\Contact)[---]
  protected 'name' => string 'myName' (length=6)
  protected 'subject' => null
```

Any idea how to make Classmethod() extract getter values from bind and merge the remaining data on setData()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is actually quiet easy to set the default value.
Define the default value in the entity:

```
class Contact
{
   protected $subject = 'Default Subject';

  // other properties and methods
}
```

In addition, you can also define the default value in the form:

```
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'subject',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Subject',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => 'Default Subject'
            ),
            'type'  => 'Text',
        ));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems ok for what comes to String but what about date data type? Php cannot initialize an object as default value. It would be nice if the Hydrator get the variable from it's getter instead right?

Comment: @Nekapps You can do that with `setDate($date = null)` and then if the value is `null` create a new `DateTime` instance. Alternatively look into [Hydration Strategies](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.stdlib.hydrator.strategy.html) add attach these to the hydrator to handle the special cases.

Comment: @Nekapps Alex is right. Either, do that in the getter by checking if it is null or you can set the default value in the constructor of the entity! YOu may extend the classmethods hydrator as [here](https://github.com/hrevert/HtMessaging/blob/master/src/HtMessaging/Stdlib/Hydrator/MessageHydrator.php)

Comment: @UjjwalOjha Ok... I don't know if the code I wrote above is correct. But with the hydrator `Classmethod`, the `bind` method does not automatically use the getter method of the entity. Is it suppose to work this way?

Comment: I could not understand what you want to say @Nekapps !

Comment: @UjjwalOjha In the code above, when I bind the entity to the form, the `$form->getData()` does not return me the default value of the subject (as this is set up in its getter method). You may try to implement the code above to understand. Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: @Nekapps You should call `$form->bind($entity)` before `$form->setData($this->getRequest()->getPost())`. I use these kind of things a lot. It must be a minor error!

Comment: @UjjwalOjha I have read your response several times before i say this, "That's what I did but it doesn't work, calling `bind` then `setData`". I'm using zf2 2.2.5. Is there something wrong with my code above?

Comment: That should not happen like that.. I am sorry.. I cannot do anything more !

Comment: Ok found the problem. I was using a service for the Form and saw that previously there was an entity which was already binded to the form. I had to use a different form instance and it works as expected. Thanks